# Re-arranging CSV table in R

Tags: r, reshape

Seeing the huge possibilities by R to avoid endless Excel-Copy-and-paste-sessions I started exploring it, but now I face trouble formatting several (15+) .csv tables. They all have the same appearance:

```
Date;Value;Name
1.1.2011;30;GWM5
1.2.2011;31;GWM5
1.3.2011;35;GWM5
1.4.2011;31;GWM5
1.1.2011;23;GWM5
1.2.2011;24;GWM5
1.3.2011;21;GWM5
1.4.2011;22;GWM5
```

As you can see, the name is constant, the date is reoccurring, only the value is variable. I need to have it in a table like this:

```
Name;date;value1;value2
GWM5;1.1.2011;30;23
GWM5;1.2.2011;31;24
GWM5;1.3.2011;35;21
GWM5;1.4.2011;31;22
```

I already tried to order, transpose and determine duplicates. But transpose (even as a function: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/transpose.php ) didn't gave me the right arrangement in individual cells (there were always 2 or more values in 1 cell) and determine duplicates only gave me single values, not rows.

Can you please help me? I would like to avoid putting them into the right order in Excel by hand.

Answer (score 3):

The base R approach would be something like this:

```
mydf <- read.csv("your.file.txt", sep=";")
mydf$time <- with(mydf, ave(rep(1, nrow(mydf)), Date, FUN = seq_along))
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar=c("Name", "Date"), timevar="time")
#           Date Name Value.1 Value.2
# 1     1.1.2011 GWM5      30      23
# 2     1.2.2011 GWM5      31      24
# 3     1.3.2011 GWM5      35      21
# 4     1.4.2011 GWM5      31      22
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems about right, although there might be an easier way:

```
d <- read.csv2(text="
Date;Value;Name
1.1.2011;30;GWM5
1.2.2011;31;GWM5
1.3.2011;35;GWM5
1.4.2011;31;GWM5
1.1.2011;23;GWM5
1.2.2011;24;GWM5
1.3.2011;21;GWM5
1.4.2011;22;GWM5")

library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
d2 <- ddply(d,"Date",transform,n=paste0("Value",seq_along(Value)))
dcast(d2,Date+Name~n,value.var="Value")
##           Date Name Value1 Value2
## 1     1.1.2011 GWM5     30     23
## 2     1.2.2011 GWM5     31     24
## 3     1.3.2011 GWM5     35     21
## 4     1.4.2011 GWM5     31     22
```

Comment: you guys are too fast, I can't compete.

Comment: @user3114046, there are other ways that might even be more efficient. A matrix indexing approach is likely to take the lead in speed, even if it takes more time to set up. It's not a competition--just an opportunities for sharing alternatives, so feel free to add :-)